# Using PowerShell, what is the command to get the MD5 hash of a file?

Tags: windows, powershell

It's been a while since I've worked with windows and I don't remember the command line to get the MD5 hash of a file.

Comment: I would have included an LMGTFY link with explainer, instead of Google: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=powershell+get+md5+hash+of+file&iie=1 

Comment: Don't, use a better hash like SHA-2. (There are use cases for MD5, but you have not explained yours.)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Powershell 4.0 you can use `Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path <file>`